# XamDataGrid Column position index: Field.Index or Field.ActualPosition.Column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Let's imagine that grid already bound to a data rows and has multiple columns.

I found that I can retrieve a given column position index by:

```cs
var fieldsLayout = grid.FieldLayouts[0];
var columnField = fieldsLayout.Fields.Single(f => f.Name == "Column Name");
int columnIndex = ... see below
```

- `columnField.Index` - If user does not changed an initial columns order
- `columnField.ActualPosition.Column` - If user has changed an initial columns order

The question is how to know whether an user has changed initial columns order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst investigating I've found that at the initial stage, when columns order has not been changed yet, `field.ActivePosition.Column` for each columns is `0` or `== field.Index`,
so by introducing following flag:

```cs
bool initialOrderChanged = fieldsLayout.Fields.Any(f => 
                                       f.ActualPosition.Column != 0 
                                       && 
                                       f.ActualPosition.Column != f.Index);
```

I can get right column position order in following way:

```
 int position = initialOrderChanged
                      ? field.ActualPosition.Column
                      : field.Index,
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the initial column list and compare the initial column list with the actual list. If there is any difference, in the order, the column order was changed.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Good idea, btw I already found a solution, will post a bit later